# Splitting list into dictionary based on value type

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have a list that contains a word followed by multiple numbers. Some are separated my spaces other by commas. I'm trying to make the word a key in a dictionary and then split each number up into a separate list and store that as the dictionaries value.

Input:

```
my_list = ['word 1234 123 1', 'word 123 43 564', 'somethingelse 123,4124,56', etc...]
```

Output:

```
my_dict = {'word': ['1234', '123', '1'],
     'word': ['123', '43', '564'], 'somethingelse': '123', '4124', '56' ]}
```

So far I have experimented with creating words to remove and also different regular expressions:

```
re.sub(r'([^\s\w]|_)+', '', str(my_list))

stopwords = ['word']
querywords = my_list.split()
resultwords = [word for word in querywords if word.lower() not in stopwords]
result = ' '.join(resultwords)

re.findall('\d+|\D+', my_list)
```

I wrote this method to split before certain words:

```
def removeBeforeX(self, x, listIn, listOut):
        for item in listIn:
            if x in item:
                a,b = item.split(x)
                listOut.append(b)
            else:
                listOut.append(item)
        return listOut
```

I don't necessarily need the word to be the key because keys must be unique in dictionaries, but I do need to separate the numbers but keep them together in a list.

Comment: You cannot have multiple key `word` in the same dictionary.

Comment: cannot have Same key word multiple times in a dict. key must be unique

Comment: please tell us what you tried, what was your approach and what was the difficulties that you faced?
This community does not provide solutions, we provide assistance for you to find a solution.

Comment: you can have multiple values names but not multiple keys names in `dic`

Comment: I gave as little information as possible as I wanted to get straight to the point. I've updated my answer with things I have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the problem?

```
>>> import re
>>> my_dict={}
>>> my_list = ['word1 1234 123 1', 'word2 123 43 564', 'somethingelse 123,4124,56']
>>> for i in my_list:
...     parts = re.split(r'[, ]', i)
...     my_dict[parts[0]] = parts[1:]
...
>>> my_dict
{'word2': ['123', '43', '564'], 'somethingelse': ['123', '4124', '56'], 'word1': ['1234', '123', '1']}
```

Obviously, you can't have the same key twice, otherwise the value will be overwritten.

A way without the re module:

```
>>> for i in my_list:
...     parts = i.replace(',', ' ').split()
...     my_dict[parts[0]] = parts[1:]
...
```

Comment: Did you really need regex for that? :P

Comment: @VasiliSyrakis: no, you can also replace each comma with a space before splitting.

Comment: we are not sure it answers the question

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Question has been edited since my answer and is no more the same. It's actually totally unclear.

Answer (score 1):

#### EDITED

#### OUTPUT A DICTIONARY

I would use partition method for the string combined with re and findall

```
import re

my_dict = {}
my_list = ['wordA 1234 123 1', 'wordB 123 43 564', 'somethingelse 123,4124,56']

for item in my_list:
    my_dict[item.partition(' ')[0]] = re.findall('\d+', item)

print my_dict
```

The above code will result in the following dictionary

```
{'wordA': ['1234', '123', '1'], 'wordB': ['123', '43', '564'], 'somethingelse': ['123', '4124', '56']}
```

**IF** you expect to have the same word more than once you will need to rewrite the loop to check for the existence of the key and append the new values to the existing list.

#### OUTPUT A LIST OF LISTS

If a dictionary is not needed, them I would use re and list comprehension

```
my_newlist = [re.findall('\d+', item) for item in my_list]

print my_newlist
```

The above code with result in the following list of lists

`[['1234', '123', '1'], ['123', '43', '564'], ['123', '4124', '56']]`​